NewsAPI collect results across all pages
I am trying to use the free service for NewsAPI to collect some news articles on a given topic. It seems like the API will only collect the results from the first page, unless you specify a different page number with the page parameter:
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='Your_API_Key')

all_articles2 = newsapi.get_everything(q="election AND (British OR England OR Britain OR (United AND Kingdom))",
                                      language='en',
                                      from_param='2024-05-12',
                                      to='2024-05-13',
                                      page = 2)

Is there a way to page through all search results in a given request?
Edit: Essentially, it looks like each requests produces a page of 100 articles. However, the totalResults might be 119, indicating that the results span two pages. How would I go about paging over the search results so that I can collect all articles over all pages.

Try making request using Python requests module to their API endpoint -
GET https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q={topic}&apiKey=API_KEY

In the documentation they have mentioned that the default value for results returned (i.e. page parameter) is 1 that's why you are only getting result for the first page, check here - https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything.
Code
import requests

api_key = 'YOUR-API-KEY'
topic = 'electric cars'
url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q={topic}&apiKey={api_key}'

results = requests.get(url)

print(results)

Make sure to use a config file or set your API key as environment variable to secure your keys, thanks.

Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to still limit language and data params with this method?

For the language you can use language parameter and I don't understand what you mean by data here.

Once again please check the link it has clear instructions as what parameters perform what kind of functions thanks.

Sorry, I meant specifying the date as I had in the original code. Unfortunately, I did try this solution and it still only shows the first page of 100 articles. Ideally, I'd like to page over the search results that span multiple pages. Not just the results from the first page.

Can you try with this parameter pageSize  in your url like - url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q={topic}&apiKey={api_key}&pageSize={5}' 

In documentation they have mentioned it like "The number of results to return per page", maybe it would work.
